# How do I restore windows 8 / hard drive after hard drive overwrite?

Tags: linux, windows-8, hard-drive, boot, fedora

So I have been a bit of an idiot... I was installing fedora and I clicked through the partitioning without much attention assuming that fedora would be installed in dual boot. It seems to have overwritten my whole hard drive. Furthermore, I can't even boot into fedora!! When i try to boot without usb the computer just goes into bios/UEFI setup screen. With USB fedora complains that secure boot is not enabled and does not boot. Enabling secure allows USB fedora to boot but not into the graphical interface - only cmd. Have not tried yet with other distros on the USB.

I don't care about data because it is all backed up on dropbox but I really want Windows 8 back because its the only distro which works properly with the touch screen. How can I restore my previous boot configuration :-(

Thanks

laptop is Asus TaiChi

Comment: If you clobbered the drive, you probably overwrote any recovery partition.  You don't mention the manufacturer of your system, but you'll likely have to contact them to get recovery media if you didn't burn any to start.

Comment: You need to reinstall Windows from scratch.

Comment: Clean wipe - reinstall - 20 Mins - you're done

Comment: Thought this may be the case... Where can I find/get the windows 8 iso?

Comment: DVD or download the 30 day demo from microsoft if you have a key

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is: Restore Windows using the restore disks you created or call Asus for a restore disk(s). BAM! Lesson learned...Ouch!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if you didn't burn recover media using the ASUS tools.

If that's the case, you should be able to purchase [recovery media](http://serviceshop.asus.com/) from ASUS.

Alternatively, you can try using any Windows 8 install disk, as the BIOS should contain the product key and install just fine.